# File Upload doesn't post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, file-upload

I tried this Drag-and-Drop File uploadfrom Aaron Vanston: https://codepen.io/aaronvanston/pen/yNYOXR

It works perfectly, all until I try to post it. I put the whole thing in a `<form>` tag and added a submit button, but after uploading an image and submitting it, both the `$_POST` and the `$_FILES` arrays are empty. I tried adding a regular file-upload input field, and that one seemed to work.

Does anyone know why the code linked above won't let me submit the file? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please provide your code. Did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag? Is your `<input>` type `file` ?

Comment: @K-Galalem i added the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` but it doesn't change the behavior. yes, the `input` is of the type `file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<input>`-Tag in the codepen was missing a `name` attribute. Adding it fixed it's functionality.